# Strange Console log in Watch OS 8: unexpectedly nil frameSpecifier. presentationDate:15:02:48.559 alwaysOnSession

Tags: swift, xcode, healthkit, watchos, watchos-8

I'm getting this error in the console running Xcode Beta 13, Series 6 Watch with Watch OS 8 beta.  It seems to be related to the new AlwaysOnSession API?  My app is a workout app that starts an `HKWorkout` and gathers heart rate data etc.  This issue seems to also be preventing my app from receiving HR samples on the watch, although it doesn't in the simulator.  Any idea what could be the cause or is it just a Watch OS 8 beta bug.

```
  2021-07-25 15:02:48.765262-0400 newFitnessApp WatchKit Extension[507:473776] [scenes] 0x15d7f590 unexpectedly nil frameSpecifier. presentationDate:15:02:48.559 alwaysOnSession:<BLSAlwaysOnSession: 0x15dc64a0; model: <BLSFrameSpecifierModel: 0x172f26e0; count: 1; first: <BLSAlwaysOnFrameSpecifier: 0x17545250; presentation interval: "15:02:48.711 07/25 (in 0 sec) : 0.016s duration"> = {
    15:02:48.711,1.00% (null)*;
}; last: <BLSAlwaysOnFrameSpecifier: 0x17545250; presentation interval: "15:02:48.711 07/25 (in 0 sec) : 0.016s duration"> = {
    15:02:48.711,1.00% (null)*;
}>; environment: <0x15eca750:myndarc.newFitnessApp.watchkitapp>>
2021-07-25 15:02:58.681115-0400 newFitnessApp WatchKit Extension[507:473776] [scenes] 0x15d7f590 unexpectedly nil frameSpecifier. presentationDate:15:02:58.643 alwaysOnSession:<BLSAlwaysOnSession: 0x15efc790; model: <BLSFrameSpecifierModel: 0x15e07be0; count: 0; first: 0x0; last: 0x0>; environment: <0x15eca750:myndarc.newFitnessApp.watchkitapp>>
2021-07-25 15:02:58.701913-0400 newFitnessApp WatchKit Extension[507:473776] [scenes] 0x15d7f590 unexpectedly nil frameSpecifier. presentationDate:15:02:58.643 alwaysOnSession:<BLSAlwaysOnSession: 0x15efc790; model: <BLSFrameSpecifierModel: 0x15e07be0; count: 0; first: 0x0; last: 0x0>; environment: <0x15eca750:myndarc.newFitnessApp.watchkitapp>>
2021-07-25 15:03:03.558903-0400 newFitnessApp WatchKit Extension[507:473776] [scenes] 0x15d7f590 unexpectedly nil frameSpecifier. presentationDate:15:03:03.438 alwaysOnSession:<BLSAlwaysOnSession: 0x15efc790; model: <BLSFrameSpecifierModel: 0x17566ca0; count: 1; first: <BLSAlwaysOnFrameSpecifier: 0x1754f180; presentation interval: "15:03:03.514 07/25 (in 0 sec) : 0.016s duration"> = {
    15:03:03.514,1.00% (null)*;
}; last: <BLSAlwaysOnFrameSpecifier: 0x1754f180; presentation interval: "15:03:03.514 07/25 (in 0 sec) : 0.016s duration"> = {
    15:03:03.514,1.00% (null)*;
}>; environment: <0x15eca750:myndarc.newFitnessApp.watchkitapp>>
```

Comment: Have you figured it out? I have the same issue with `handleRemoteNowPlayingActivity()`

Comment: @Vitaly for now I disabled Always On in info.plist